# Is it possible to stop iCloud Drive sync on macOS High Sierra (10.13) over a cellular connection?

Tags: macos, macos-highsierra, icloud

I don't know why but my iCloud drive sync always has gigabytes to transfer. It doesn't really matter for me unless I'm using my iPhone's 4G connection.

I need a way to stop iCloud Drive sync when using cellular internet on macOS High Sierra (10.13). Is there a way to do this?

Comment: There's a 3rd party app mentioned on https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/296450/85275 - I've never tried it myself.